# Binding DataViz chart locally using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I'm trying to bind a DataViz pie chart locally using the Kendo UI Angular directives but keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at h (http://localhost:51717/Scripts/kendo/kendo.dataviz.min.js:11:5351)
    at Object.o.aggregate (http://localhost:51717/Scripts/kendo/kendo.dataviz.min.js:11:20999)
    at g (http://localhost:51717/Scripts/kendo/kendo.dataviz.min.js:11:5624)
    at ct.extend._process (http://localhost:51717/Scripts/kendo/kendo.dataviz.min.js:11:31624)
    at ct.extend.success (http://localhost:51717/Scripts/kendo/kendo.dataviz.min.js:11:28852)
    at Object.proxy [as success] (http://localhost:51717/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js:841:14)
    at ct.extend.read (http://localhost:51717/Scripts/kendo/kendo.web.min.js:11:21673)
    at http://localhost:51717/Scripts/kendo/kendo.dataviz.min.js:11:28381
    at ct.extend._queueRequest (http://localhost:51717/Scripts/kendo/kendo.dataviz.min.js:11:30001)
    at ct.extend.read (http://localhost:51717/Scripts/kendo/kendo.dataviz.min.js:11:28266)
```

**HTML**

```
<div kendo-chart k-options="pie" k-data-source="countries" />
```

**Angular**

```
$scope.countries = {
    data: [
        {
            category: "Asia",
            value: 53.8,
            color: "#9de219"
        }, {
            category: "Europe",
            value: 16.1,
            color: "#90cc38"
        }, {
            category: "Latin America",
            value: 11.3,
            color: "#068c35"
        }, {
            category: "Africa",
            value: 9.6,
            color: "#006634"
        }, {
            category: "Middle East",
            value: 5.2,
            color: "#004d38"
        }, {
            category: "North America",
            value: 3.6,
            color: "#033939"
        }
    ]
};

$scope.pie = {
    title: {
        position: "bottom",
        text: "Share of Internet Population Growth, 2007 - 2012"
    },
    legend: {
        visible: false
    },
    chartArea: {
        background: ""
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
        labels: {
            visible: true,
            background: "transparent",
            template: "#= category #: #= value#%"
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: "pie",
        field: "value",
        categoryField: "category"
    }],
    tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        format: "{0}%"
    }
};
```

Comment: which version of Kendo UI are you using? can you add the section where you include the kendo scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your libraries to ensure you are using supported versions. Are you using the latest version of KendoUI? According to the [KendoUI->Angular repo on GitHub](https://github.com/kendo-labs/angular-kendo#angularjs-integration-for-kendo-ui) you need:

- jQuery v1.9.1 (not sure if later versions are supported)
- Angular v1.0.5
- KendoUI vCurrent

I created [a working example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/OSudIzEH/6) for you to check out. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Angular + KendoUI DataViz" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgithub.com/kendo-labs/angular-kendo/master/build/angular-kendo.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="chart-example">
  <div ng-controller="ChartController">    
    <div kendo-chart k-options="pie" k-data-source="countries" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

...

```
var app = angular.module('chart-example', ['kendo.directives']);

function ChartController($scope) {
  $scope.pie = {
    title: {
        position: "bottom",
        text: "Share of Internet Population Growth, 2007 - 2012"
    },
    legend: {
        visible: false
    },
    chartArea: {
        background: ""
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
        labels: {
            visible: true,
            background: "transparent",
            template: "#= category #: #= value#%"
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: "pie",
        field: "value",
        categoryField: "category"
    }],
    tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        format: "{0}%"
    }
  };

  $scope.countries = {
    data: [
        {
            category: "Asia",
            value: 53.8,
            color: "#9de219"
        }, {
            category: "Europe",
            value: 16.1,
            color: "#90cc38"
        }, {
            category: "Latin America",
            value: 11.3,
            color: "#068c35"
        }, {
            category: "Africa",
            value: 9.6,
            color: "#006634"
        }, {
            category: "Middle East",
            value: 5.2,
            color: "#004d38"
        }, {
            category: "North America",
            value: 3.6,
            color: "#033939"
        }
    ]
  };
}
```

Comment: Switching my script references to use kendo.all.min.js fixed it. I was only referenceing kendo.dataviz and kendo.ui.

Comment: The working example isn't working. I am trying to use it to learn how to use dataviz in angular but something is wrong...